# Interpretation of the result of ?@

Tags: system, system-variables

This might be a very trivial question but as a beginner, I don't know the answer. I was exploring `?` and after running a cell containing `?@`, I got an interesting result:

[image]

However, I'm not sure about its exact interpretation. The answer contains two parts, a `` Global` `` part that shows the list of all the global variables that I have defined (or were created as a result of my code). But what is the `` System` `` part, and what does `?@`do to get them?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. The full form of `?@` is `Information["@", LongForm -> False]`.
2. `LongForm -> False` means use the short form of `Information`, which calls `Names["@"]` (or a utility that both `Information` and `Names` use) to find the symbols which it should retrieve.
3. `Names` interprets "@" as

   > match one or more characters, but not uppercase letters

So you are getting a short form display from [`Information`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Information.html) for all the symbols that match the wildcard character "@" as described under the 3rd bullet point of **Details and Options** under [`Names`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Names.html)

Comment: Wow I was way over my head! Thanks.

Comment: If I may ask, what are those that look like Greek letters with dots above and below that show in the system part?

Comment: @MathX. See **Formal Symbols** under [Letters and Letter-like Forms](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html)

Comment: Thanks! This is a super useful link.

Comment: How to get the `FullForm` of `?@`?

Comment: Sorry for asking a stupid question. The answer of my comment is `FullForm@Unevaluated@?@`

Comment: @luyuwuli, or you can use `Hold[]` and take whatever is inside it after using `FullForm[]`.

Comment: Yes. However, at that time, I was stuck by the special interpretation of `?` by the front end, `FullForm[Hold[?@]]` won't work, one has to use prefix form `FullForm@Hold@?@`.